# Animation (global offset) on Grid.Row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, silverlight-5.0

I got this UserControl which is a Grid with around 10 rows and 10 columns. Each cell contains 1 textblock or 1-6 images.
What I want to do is animate all elements on each row to slide in. However I can't find a way to animate the whole Grid.Row to do that.

I can't wrap all elements in a stackpanel/canvas either since that puts them into the same column...

Anyone has a solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried FluidMoveBehavior attached to the grid itself? I think it could deliver what you're looking for by modifying the EaseIn.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.I played around with a little and it seemed to not work very well when you added many elements at the same time. The animation only played for the last added element and the previous did not have an animation. Aside from that it seemed that you couldn't control from which direction the element would come from. I wanted my elements to come from outside the screen, but I couldn't get that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've come up with a working solution and it is working. Maybe not that elegant but it does what it is supposed to do and works very well on a Lumia 920 device.

```
void CreateLoadAnimationForRow(int row, int startTime)
    {
        foreach (var child in LayoutRoot.Children.Cast<FrameworkElement>().Where(x => Grid.GetRow(x) == row))
        {
            AddToStoryboard(child, startTime);
        }
    }
    void AddToStoryboard(FrameworkElement element, int startTime)
    {
        element.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();
        var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            From = -200,
            To = 0,
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
            BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(startTime)
        };

        var objectAnimationUsingKeyFrames = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames()
        {
            BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(startTime + 10)
        };
        var discreteObjectKeyFrame = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame()
        {
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)),
            Value = Visibility.Visible
        };

        objectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(discreteObjectKeyFrame);

        IEasingFunction easingFunction = new SineEase();
        easingFunction.Ease(2);
        doubleAnimation.EasingFunction = easingFunction;

        Storyboard.SetTarget(objectAnimationUsingKeyFrames, element);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(objectAnimationUsingKeyFrames, new PropertyPath("Visibility"));

        Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, element);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath("(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"));

        storyboardSlideIn.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
        storyboardSlideIn.Children.Add(objectAnimationUsingKeyFrames);

    }
```